# Unplug power cable of my monitor

Tags: display, power, cable

Is it oké that I unplug my power cable of the monitor every night? Or is it bad for the monitor?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Superisee.com.  This queztion may be closed as opinion baseed, but here is mine - It is unlikely to be bad for the monitor as the damage caused to electronics by turning them on is due to inrush current (ie the burst of electricity at startup).  This will not be massively different between sleep mode and full off. This will, howrver, depend somewhat on the specific monitor design.

Comment: @davidgo LoL, did you read your comment?

Comment: Are you unable to use the power button?

Comment: You'd be better off using the power button.  Unplugging the power cord, especially if you pull on the power cord, will weaken the wire to plug connections.  Even a power bar with a power button is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not harmful for the monitor, if you turn it off first,
but it may be harmful to the plug.

I don't how many plug/unplug repetition this cable can take before failing.

In any case, turning off the monitor should be enough for most cases.
Why do you want to unplug it.

Comment: You are correct about the plug but also the socket on monitor side may take damage over the time.

Comment: Yes, both sides of the connection.

Comment: It will take a long time to damage an AC connection. Kitchen appliances are unplugged all the time. Decades later the plug and socket still work.

Comment: @John: My kitchen appliances are not plugged in-out every day. However, I have had phones with bad charging socket after only months of daily plugging. I have also seen computers with bad power sockets after brutal plug insertion. People do make errors and some material is sub-par.

Answer (score 0):

It will not harm the monitor to unplug the power cord. There is no need to as modern devices will turn themselves off and reduce power. But no harm to unplug it. Also check if it has a power switch.

Note: Whether a device like a monitor or other similar electronic equipment has a "soft" power switch or real (clunk, clunk) power switch, the external (AC Side) of the power is disconnected. This is the very same as unplugging the device in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

While I completely agree that is safe to pull the power on a standard LCD monitor, it is always best practice to properly power off any electronic device before pulling the power cord.

Comment: For LCD I agree.But I think it should be mentioned that for OLED displays (not very common today but who knows) disconnecting power may harm the monitor as it interrupts the anti-burn-in program that often happens if the monitor is not used.

Comment: @Robert I am as guilty as the next person in not following "best practices."  However, they *should* be mentioned, regardless of whether people will follow them or not.  Sooner or later, we all get bit in the ass by taking shortcuts.